# Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createUser'

Tags: javascript, meteor

So i'm having trouble invoking the standard Meteor Accounts.createUser function. I'm trying to implement an accounts system using the meteor accounts-base and accounts-password packages. The project is on Meteor 1.3 with React.

When i invoke Accounts.createUser(userObject), i get "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createUser'" with some cryptic mess behind it.

My code:

```
onSignUp(e) {
e.preventDefault();

let email = $(e.target).find("[name=email]").val(),
    password = $(e.target).find("[name=password]").val(),
    confirmPassword = $(e.target).find("[name=confirmPassword]").val();

if (password == confirmPassword) {
  Accounts.createUser({
    mail: email,
    password: password
  }, function(error){
    if (error) {
      Bert.alert( err.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right' );
    } else {
      Bert.alert( "Welcome!", 'success', 'growl-top-right');
      console.log(userObject);

      FlowRouter.go('/');
    }
  });
```

This is currently in my client folder but i tried moving the createAccount call to a server side method but it gives me the same error.

I tried running Meteor in debug mode but i'm having trouble understanding what's happening. From what i could understand while logging in there was either no result or the log in could not be validated.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Should it be email and not mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Accounts.createUser({
    mail: email,
    password: password
  }
```

with

```
Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,      //email
        password: password,
        profile :'default-group',
      }
```

Also, shift the account creation code to server side.

Refer : [Meteor Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser)

Comment: Hi @Ankit, please how to switch the account creation code to server side? Any example in this senario?

Comment: @Awa which package are you using? accounts-password or useraccounts:core? Please share the code and issue as separate question.